# QStyledItemDelegate: commit QComboBox value to model on click

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qcombobox, qitemdelegate

I am setting a `QStyledItemDelegate` on my model for a particular field, and returning a `QComboBox` from `QStyledItemDelegate::createEditor`

```
QComboBox* createEditor(QWidget* parent)
{
    QComboBox* cb = new QComboBox(parent);

    cb->addItem("UNDEFINED");
    cb->addItem("TEST");
    cb->addItem("OSE");
    cb->addItem("TSE");

    return cb;
}

void setEditorData(QWidget* editor, const QModelIndex& index)
{
    QComboBox* cb = qobject_cast<QComboBox*>(editor);
    if (!cb)
        throw std::logic_error("editor is not a combo box");

    QString value = index.data(Qt::EditRole).toString();
    int idx = cb->findText(value);
    if (idx >= 0)
        cb->setCurrentIndex(idx);

    cb->showPopup();
}
```

This is working fine, and when I select the field in question I am shown a combo box.

[image: combobox open]

When I select an option from the drop-down list, the combobox closes and the item is displayed with a drop-down icon next to it:

[image: selected]

At this point I would like the `QStyledItemDelegate::setModelData` function to be called, so that selecting an item in the list commits the data to the model.

However, I am required to first press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to commit the data (whereby the drop-down icon disappears)

[image: committed]

```
void setModelData(QWidget* editor, QAbstractItemModel* model, const QModelIndex& index)
{
    QComboBox* cb = qobject_cast<QComboBox*>(editor);
    if (!cb)
        throw std::logic_error("editor is not a combo box");

    model->setData(index, cb->currentText(), Qt::EditRole);
}
```

**Question:**

How can I configure my `QComboBox` to **automatically** commit the data when the user selects an item in the list and the combobox list closes, rather than requiring the additional press of `Enter`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to issue the signal `commitData` and `closeEditor` when an item is selected as shown in the following example:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QStandardItemModel>
#include <QListView>
#include <QStyledItemDelegate>
#include <QComboBox>

class ComboBoxDelegate: public QStyledItemDelegate{
public:
    using QStyledItemDelegate::QStyledItemDelegate;
    QWidget *createEditor(QWidget *parent, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const{
        Q_UNUSED(option)
        Q_UNUSED(index)

        QComboBox* editor = new QComboBox(parent);
        connect(editor,  QOverload<int>::of(&QComboBox::activated),
                this, &ComboBoxDelegate::commitAndCloseEditor);
        editor->addItems({"UNDEFINED", "TEST", "OSE", "TSE"});

        return editor;
    }
    void setEditorData(QWidget *editor, const QModelIndex &index) const{
        QComboBox* cb = qobject_cast<QComboBox*>(editor);
        if (!cb)
            throw std::logic_error("editor is not a combo box");

        QString value = index.data(Qt::EditRole).toString();
        int idx = cb->findText(value);
        if (idx >= 0)
            cb->setCurrentIndex(idx);
        cb->showPopup();
    }
private:
    void commitAndCloseEditor(){
        QComboBox *editor = qobject_cast<QComboBox *>(sender());
        emit commitData(editor);
        emit closeEditor(editor);
    }
};


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QListView view;

    QStandardItemModel model;

    for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
        model.appendRow(new QStandardItem("UNDEFINED"));
    }
    view.setItemDelegate(new ComboBoxDelegate(&view));
    view.setModel(&model);
    view.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```